# How do I throw a message if there are no posts to display

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I am displaying an array of posts by the following code. When there are no posts to display, I want to print a notification, e.g. "No posts to display". How can this be done?

```php
<?php
    while ( have_posts() ) :
        the_post();
?>
        <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
        <section class="intro">
        <?php the_content(); ?> 
        </section>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
        <h2>Latest Events</h2>

<?php
    query_posts( array( 'category__and' => array(8) ) );
    if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) :
        the_post(); 
?>

        <article class="events clearfix">
            <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            <div class="date">
                <span class="month"><?php the_time('M') ?></span>
                <span class="day"><?php the_time('d') ?></span>
            </div>
        </article>


<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example you would have to modify your code as follows:

```
// Display latest events
// ...
if ( have_posts() ) {
    // ...
} else {
    echo '<article class="events clearfix">';
    echo '<p>No posts to display.</p>';
    echo '</article>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`have_posts()` returns `true` when there are posts to display, and `false` when there aren't any (see the [Documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/have_posts)).

You can easily evaluate the value of this, and display your message accordingly. For example:

```
if(!have_posts())
{
    echo 'No posts to display&hellip;';
}
else
{
    // code to display your posts here.
}
```